# Filter/skip missing API array results not working in React (Hooks)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm building a React app (with hooks) that gets data from the NASA image search API. Turns out, not all query results actually have an image attached. If I search "cars" I get an empty array. If I search "space" I get the word "undefined" in console.log. 
Image of the missing items in API: 
[nasa image results](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fts8pgbnoao1i2q/nasa_links.jpg)

GitHub: https://github.com/irene-rojas/nasa/tree/searchErrorHandling

I was advised to separate the filtering function away from setData. I have tried two versions of a function, one using filter and map, the other using if then map. I want to create a 1:1 match to pass data to the ImageSearch component.

State

```
const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
        "id": "",
        "title": "",
        "date": "",
        "description": "",
        "src": ""
    }
]);


const imageSearch = () => {
    axios.get(`https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?q=${query}`)
    .then(res => {

setData(transformImgSearch(res.data.collection.items.slice(0,6)));
        console.log(res.data.collection.items.slice(0,6));
        // endpoint testing
        // console.log(res.data.collection.items[0].links[0].href);
    });
    console.log(data);
};
```

Function attempt 1:

```
    function transformImgSearch(props) {
    props.filter(prop => 
        prop.links).map(prop => 
            [
                {
                    "id": prop.data[0].nasa_id,
                    "title": prop.data[0].title,
                    "date": prop.data[0].date_created,
                    "description": prop.data[0].description,
                    "src": prop.links[0].href
                }
            ]);
        console.log(data);
    }
```

Function attempt 2

```
function transformImgSearch(props) {
    if (props.links) {
        props.map(prop => 
        [
            {
                "id": prop.data[0].nasa_id,
                "title": prop.data[0].title,
                "date": prop.data[0].date_created,
                "description": prop.data[0].description,
                "src": prop.links[0].href
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

The component I ultimately want to use the data, mapped 1:1 with state.

```
        {data.map(image => {
            return (
                <ImageSearch 
                    key={image.id}
                    title={image.title}
                    date={image.date}
                    description={image.description}
                    id={image.id}
                    src={image.href}
                />
            )
        })}
```

This console.log(res.data.collection.items.slice(0,6)); returns the correct basic data, but attempts at returning the data to match the array in state don't work.

Comment: Your `.map` callback should not return an array but an object. So change your `.map(prop => [ {...} ]);` to `.map(prop => ( {...} ));`

Comment: Thank you for responding. I just tried that in both functions with no success. For testing, I disabled the ImageSearch component, but once re-enabled, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: Oh yeah, an additional problem is that your `transformImgSearch` function does not return anything. You need to add a `return` before the `props.filter`.

Comment: Thank you, that was a big help! Though I'm only getting alt text in the ImageSearch component, not the image itself. Everything else appears correctly.

Comment: Here's the current code: 
    function transformImgSearch(props) {
        return (
        props.filter(prop => 
            prop.links).map(prop => 
                (
                    {
                        "id": prop.data[0].nasa_id,
                        "title": prop.data[0].title,
                        "date": prop.data[0].date_created,
                        "description": prop.data[0].description,
                        "src": prop.links[0].href
                    }
                )
            )
        );
    }

Comment: That is because you are passing it as `src={image.href}` when it should be `src={image.src}`

Comment: That fixed it! Wow I feel silly.